# как разместить view по верх другого view

Tags: java, android, view

Хочу разместить две кнопки так чтобы они выглядели как на скринах. Чтобы они не занимали место в основном списке элементов и выглядели как будто они отдельны.Можно ли ImageView или ImageButton так разместить?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Это `FAB` - `FloatingActionButton` внутри `CoordinatorLayout` из `support-design` либы гугла

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Спасибо большое.